Can an ample line bundle equipped with a metric which is negative somewhere?
Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold and $L$ a holomorphic line bundle on $X$. As is wellknown, $L$ is ample if and only if $L$ admits a positive Hermitian metric (i.e., its curvature form is positive everywhere).
Question: Can an ample line bundle be equipped with a Hermitian metric whose curvature form is negative somewhere?
Clues: Of course  an ample line bundle whose curvature form is non-positive definiteness everywhere does not exist:  if such hermitian metric exist, then we can connstruct a strictly psh on this compact manifold, contradicts with the fact that there exists no strictly psh function on a compact complex manifold.

Can you find a $(1,1)$-form in the same cohomology class that is not everywhere positive?

@TedShifrin  Sorry, I don't have such examples at hand; otherwise, I wouldn't be asking this question. Do you know such example? I have added some additional explanations in the post to clarify that an ample  line bundle whose curvature form is non-positive definiteness everywhere  does not exist.

Why not start with a Riemann surface, even $\Bbb P^1$? As I said, ampleness is determined by $c_1$, but you can take many representatives of the same cohomology class.

@TedShifrin  Thank you, I will try.

In the hope a picture is worth a thousand words:

As a guard if not:

 The complex projective line $X$ is a compact holomorphic manifold, whose tangent bundle $L$ is holomorphic and ample. The diagram shows an isometric embedding of a metric on $L$ whose curvature is negative on a zone about the equator. Hopefully this pointedly impresses the importance of drawing upon basic geometric intuition.

